# not showing selected array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, fetch

im having problems trying to show the selected items array. I mean, i have a list that shows a table with ID, Name,Apellido. (name is the one with dinamic array [].

When i se the table everthing is allright, but when i click the edit button, i get right id, the right apellido and name gets the last array inserted.

If i click to edit ID number 5 and i have 15, it will show me the 15 instead of number 5 (the selected one).

could anyone find what im doing wrong?

thanks

this are the files im using

list.php

update.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="inputmultiplicad"; // Mysql username 
$password="inputmultiplicado"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="inputmultiplicado"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="input_field"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$id=$_GET['id'];
$first_name=$_GET['first_name'];

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

// Retrieve data from database to implode/explode
$select_tbl=mysql_query("select * from input_field");
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_object($select_tbl))
{

echo $id;
$r=$fetch->firstname;



$i=explode(",",$r);



}

?>



<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="main contenedor">

    <header>
      <section class="logo">LOGO</section> <!--logo-->


    </header>
    <div id="contenedor">


      <div class="insertar_formulario">
        <h3>Editar Cliente</h3>
        <h3>id</h3>

     <? echo $rows['id'];
     ?>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">

        <section class="nombre"><h2>Nombre</h2>
            <?
           for($x = 0; $x < count($i); $x++ )
    {

      echo "<input type='text' name='firstname[]' value='$i[$x]'><input type='button' value='+'/><br />";
};
    ?>
        </section>


        <section class="apellido"><h2>Apellido</h2>
<input type='text' name='apellido[]' value='<? echo $rows['apellido']; ?>'/>
        </section>


        <section class="enviar">

          <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
          <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
        </section>

        </form>
      </div>




    </div><!--contenedor-->



  </div> <!--main contenedor-->

</body>
</html>


<?php
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

list.php

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="inputmultiplicad"; // Mysql username 
$password="inputmultiplicado"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="inputmultiplicado"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="input_field"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");





$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><strong>List data from mysql </strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="center"><strong>ID</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>

<td align="center"><strong><a href="agregar_cliente.php">Add+</a></strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
    <td><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['firstname']; ?></td>


<td align="center"><a href="ver_update.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">Editar</a></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="delete_ac.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">delete</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, it was something stupid

Change update.php

this:

```
$select_tbl=mysql_query("select * from input_field");
```

to:

```
$select_tbl=mysql_query("select * from input_field WHERE id='$id'");
```